# Is there anything that vararg operator can do but arg table can't?

Tags: lua, operators

In Lua 5.1, `...` (vararg operator) is added, replaces the `arg` table.
A table which contains variable number of arguments like arg can be created easily `local arg = {...}` and has much more uses than the new vararg operator.
I think there must be a reason behind this. Nevertheless, I can't find any use of the vararg operator

Comment: See for instance http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2010-05/msg00494.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`...` allows you to use the argument list right away. This is more convenient than having to get them from a table first. It is also much clearer as you don't have to get your arguments from some hidden `arg` variable.

```
function myPrint(...)
  print("I print:", ...)
end
```

Instead of

```
function myPrint(...)
  print("I print:", unpack(arg))
end
```